# Outputting String in GUI from IF statements

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to output this piece of string from an if statement into a GUI field and while the program is compiling, the answer field only outputs the last statement, while the other button works fine... I have attached the code..

The else if attached to the try statement, those if statements either aren't running or something, but it outputs the final statement only.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Assignment2 implements ActionListener {
    JLabel ans, ans2;
    JTextField text1, text2;

    public void displayWindow(){
        JFrame frame= new JFrame ("BMI Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout (new GridLayout (5,2,7,10));

        text1= new JTextField();
        text2= new JTextField();

        JButton buttonBMI= new JButton ("BMI (Body Mass Index)");
        buttonBMI.setActionCommand ("bmi");
        buttonBMI.addActionListener (this);

        JButton buttonH= new JButton ("Am I Healthy?");
        buttonH.setActionCommand ("health");
        buttonH.addActionListener (this);

        ans= new JLabel();
        ans2= new JLabel();

        frame.add (new JLabel ("Height (m)"));
        frame.add (text1);
        frame.add (new JLabel ("Weight (kg)"));
        frame.add (text2);
        frame.add (buttonBMI);
        frame.add (buttonH);
        frame.add (new JLabel ("Answer: "));
        frame.add (ans);
        frame.add (new JLabel ("Answer: "));
        frame.add (ans2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            try {
                double a= Double.parseDouble (text1.getText());
                double b= Double.parseDouble (text2.getText());
                double answer=0;
                double height=0;
                String answer2= "";

                String command = e.getActionCommand();

                if (command.equals ("bmi")){
                    height = Math.pow (a,2);
                    answer = b / height;
                    ans.setText ("" +answer);
                }
                else if (command.equals ("health")){
                    if (answer > 30){
                        ans2.setText ("You are Obese");

                    }
                    else if (answer > 29.9 && answer < 24.9 ){
                        ans2.setText ("You are Overweight");

                    }
                    else if (answer > 25 && answer < 18.5){
                        ans2.setText ("You are of Normal Weight");

                    }
                    else if (answer < 18.5){
                        ans2.setText("You are Underweight");

                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ans.setText ("Please use Numbers");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you split declaration of text1 and initialisation?

Comment: It was just the way I was taught

Answer (score 0):

The statement which initializes `answer` in your code is in the `if` statement which compares the command with "bmi". If the command is not "bmi", the statement is not executed. You need to move it outside the `if` statement.

Comment: The variable *answer* is explicitly initialized outside the if statement (to 0).

Answer (score 0):

This if statement

```
else if (answer < 18.5){ ... }
```

is always true because the value of the variable `answer` is always `0`. I see you are assigning a value to the `answer` variable inside the first if block. You can try to declare the `answer` variable into the global scope so you can retain the value assigned in the first if block.

Also these two statements

```
answer > 29.9 && answer < 24.9

answer > 25 && answer < 18.5
```

are always false. The `answer` value cannot be greater than 29.9 and less than 24.9 at the same time.

Try this out

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Assignment2 implements ActionListener {
    JLabel ans, ans2;
    JTextField text1, text2;
    double answer=0;
    double height=0;

    public void displayWindow(){
        JFrame frame= new JFrame ("BMI Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout (new GridLayout (5,2,7,10));

        text1= new JTextField();
        text2= new JTextField();

        JButton buttonBMI= new JButton ("BMI (Body Mass Index)");
        buttonBMI.setActionCommand ("bmi");
        buttonBMI.addActionListener (this);

        JButton buttonH= new JButton ("Am I Healthy?");
        buttonH.setActionCommand ("health");
        buttonH.addActionListener (this);

        ans= new JLabel();
        ans2= new JLabel();

        frame.add (new JLabel ("Height (m)"));
        frame.add (text1);
        frame.add (new JLabel ("Weight (kg)"));
        frame.add (text2);
        frame.add (buttonBMI);
        frame.add (buttonH);
        frame.add (new JLabel ("Answer: "));
        frame.add (ans);
        frame.add (new JLabel ("Answer: "));
        frame.add (ans2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            try {
                double a= Double.parseDouble (text1.getText());
                double b= Double.parseDouble (text2.getText());
                String answer2= "";

                String command = e.getActionCommand();

                if (command.equals ("bmi")){
                    height = Math.pow (a,2);
                    answer = b / height;
                    ans.setText ("" +answer);
                }
                else if (command.equals ("health")){
                    if (answer > 30){
                        ans2.setText ("You are Obese");

                    }
                    else if (answer > 24.9 && answer < 29.9 ){
                        ans2.setText ("You are Overweight");

                    }
                    else if (answer > 18.5&& answer < 25){
                        ans2.setText ("You are of Normal Weight");

                    }
                    else if (answer < 18.5){
                        ans2.setText("You are Underweight");

                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ans.setText ("Please use Numbers");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Well I moved the answer = b/ height outside the if and the ans.setText ("" + answer) now it's only saying "You're obese" and I changed the if statements as suggested by Flood2d

Comment: The variable *answer* is never used outside the try-block, so it is bad style making it an instance variable. Global scope is something else.